# Is it possible to pass cell value to VBA "dynamically"?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "table" in Excel:

```
      A            B          C 
1   Value1      Susan       Button
2   Value2      Peter       Button
3   Value3      Mark        Button
```

I would like to send e-mail from Excel when hit the "button" to person who's button clicked.

**Example:**

If I hit button in row2 then send e-mail to Peter like:

```
Dear Peter,

 Value2  Value2  Value2  Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2

Your sincerely..
```

Is it possible to pass Excel cell value to VBA "dynamically"?

I would like to write only one SUB to button and use in every row, but I don't know how to refer to cells based on which button pressed in which row.

For e-mail sending I use this, which works well:

```
Sub Send_Email_Using_VBA()
    Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
    Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
    Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
    Email_Subject = "Trying to send email using VBA"
    Email_Send_From = "test"
    Email_Send_To = "test"
    Email_Body = "You have successfully sent an e-mail using VBA !!!!"
    On Error GoTo debugs
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
    With Mail_Single
        .Subject = Email_Subject
        .To = Email_Send_To
        .cc = Email_Cc
        .BCC = Email_Bcc
        .Body = Email_Body
        .send
    End With
debugs:
    If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using standard form objects and not ActiveX controls, you can use something like:

```
Dim rowNumber As Long

rowNumber = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
```

This will return the row number of the cell that the button's top-left corner resides in.

Comment: Thank you ill check it as soon as í arrive home

Comment: You must be using the code in the wrong place - this needs to be inside of a procedure, and that procedure should be triggered by pressing the button

Comment: im using the above code. i put your code to the second row. The original code run well when i click on the button

Comment: when i click on the play button in the vba editor, the Shapes word highlited and a pop up message says the above error text.

Comment: You can't run this code from pressing the play button - you need to assign your sub to a button on the worksheet and then press the button to run the code. `Application.Caller` requires an object which can only be passed when it _calls_ the sub. Your question implies that you already have the button set up and that you're calling the code from the button.

Comment: sorry, im sure that my fault, but if i click on the button than the vba editor open and the same error message show :(

Comment: without actually seeing your workbook it's impossible for me to see why it's happening. Only thing I can think of is just to make sure you're not using an ActiveX control

Comment: i got it...i have to use "ActiveSheet"   rowNumber = ActiveSheet. Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row   Thank you!!

Comment: Ah yeah, that would help - d'oh! Don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped :)

Comment: sure! Thank you again!